# NPM run dev is not working, receiving error in terminal

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server

I updated my packages to the latest Webpack and Webpack-Dev-Server.  When I run `npm run dev` it produces an error I cannot resolve through searching as well.  It keeps coming up related to an issue with 2.1.0 which is not the version I am using.

I have installed the latest versions of Webpack-Dev-Server at 3.3.1

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-cli@ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-cli@ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/briansantos/.npm/_logs/2019-04-21T05_45_18_048Z-debug.log
```

NPM run dev not working properly as it should be.

This is what the log is saying below.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v9.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle vue-cli@~predev: vue-cli@
6 info lifecycle vue-cli@~dev: vue-cli@
7 verbose lifecycle vue-cli@~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vue-cli@~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/briansantos/code/VueFiltersMixins/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
9 verbose lifecycle vue-cli@~dev: CWD: /Users/briansantos/code/VueFiltersMixins
10 silly lifecycle vue-cli@~dev: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot' ]
11 silly lifecycle vue-cli@~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vue-cli@~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: vue-cli@ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:160:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid vue-cli@
15 verbose cwd /Users/briansantos/code/VueFiltersMixins
16 verbose Darwin 18.5.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v9.4.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vue-cli@ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vue-cli@ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What do the logs in ` /Users/briansantos/.npm/_logs/2019-04-21T05_45_18_048Z-debug.log` say?

Comment: I will add the log in the original question as it is too long to add in the comments.